# De-serialising nested child objects when parsing JSON with C# and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

Is there a better way when querying JSON with C# and Linq, to retrieve the child objects for the following JSON / code?

The object models have a 'Data' class with integer id, string value and 'Item' properties.

The 'Item' class has integer id and string value properties.

```
{
"data":[
    {            
        "id" : 123,
        "value" : "Something",
        "childObject":{
            "id" : 345,
            "value" : "Something else",
        },
    },
    {
        "id" : 467,
        "value" : "Nothing",
    }
]
}
```

For the above I am parsing like so:

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
JArray jsonArr = jsonObj.SelectToken("data") as JArray;
if (jsonArr.Count == 0)
{
   return new List<Data>();
}
else
{
   return jsonArr.Select(o => new Data((int)o["id"], (string)o["value"], o["childObject"] == null ? null : new Item((int)o["childObject"]["id"], (string)o["childObject"]["value"]))).ToList();
}
```

Were the child object an array of 'Items' I could replace the last Data constructor parameter with something like this:

```
o["childObject"].Count() == 0 ? 
    new List<Item>() : 
    o["childObject"].Select(i => new Item((int)i["id"], (string)i["value"]))).ToList()));
```

which reads better to me, though may be no better?

New to LINQ and JSON.NET so all advice welcome.

Comment: Insert your code using [4-space](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), I thought something was wrong with my computer or my eyes when I saw those weird tiny gray blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact structure you could just build a class/set of classes with the same structure. So you would have

```
public class RootObject{
  public List<DataObject> data{ get; set;}
}

public class DataObject {
   public int id { get; set;}
   public string value { get; set; }
   public List<DataObject> childObject{ get; set;}
}
```

And then you could just deserialize it to your own data type and then transform it to any other types you might need.

```
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
var jsonArr = deserializedData.data;
if (jsonArr.Count == 0)
{
   return new List<Data>();
}
else
{
  return jsonArr.Select(o => new Data(o.id, o.value, o.childObject.Select(c=>new Item {id= c.id, value = c.value }).ToList());
}
```

you don't even need to check for jsonArr.Count just return

```
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
var jsonArr = deserializedData.data;
return jsonArr.Select(o => new Data(o.id, o.value, o.childObject.Select(c=>new Item {id= c.id, value = c.value }).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I would do things in XML with Attributes to change names as required, but sadly I have no access to the model, hence the LINQ query.

Comment: Cheers for the update, that would likely work and would read better in the code but I had hoped to do it either in a single linq query or at least without the need for intermediate objects. I have added a 'GetChildObject(JToken) method just now which makes it more readable at least.